# Cant use Spring rest endpoints in Postman now that I added Spring Security + Okta

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I have a Spring Rest App and also a Native App in Okta. I added the @EnableOauth2So in my Configuration class (I don't have a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class), and all the necessary info in the application.yml in order to connect with OKTA.

When I use the browser, everything works as expected. My rest endpoints are redirected to the okta login page, then I enter my okta credentials, and it redirects me to my rest endpoint. The session is saved as expected.

However, I'm failing to use my rest endpoints with Postman. I have only managed to get an access_token and id_token (token_type : bearer) form the okta endpoint /v1/token. The grant_type is password and scope is openid

I don't know how to use the access_token/id_token in order to successfully call my rest endpoints from Postman. I have tried adding them as a Authorization Bearer header, but no success.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There should be two options

1. Add header "Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}"
2. Send it as queryparam http://test.api.com?access_token={{access_token}}

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately none of those options works.